# HtmlAgilityPack scraping "href"

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I wrote this code.:

Warning, the link point to adult site!!!

```
        var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = getHtmlWeb.Load("http://xhamster.com/movies/2808613/jewel_is_a_sexy_cougar_who_loves_to_fuck_lucky_younger_guys.html");
        var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'noFlash')]"); 


        if (aTags != null)

        foreach (var aTag in aTags)
        {

            var href = aTag.Attributes["href"].Value;

            textBox2.Text = href;

        }
```

I got an error when i try run this programm.

If i put other things in "var href" for example.:

```
var href = aTag.InnerHtml
```

I got the inner text, and i can see there the "href=" link, and some other datas.

But i need only the link after the href!

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting `div` elements. A `div` element can't have `href` attribute.If you want to get href's of anchor tags you can use:

```
var hrefs = aTags.Descendants("a")
           .Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href","")) 
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello. If i use your code, and put this : textBox2.Text = hrefs.ToString(); , i got this in my textbox.: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @user3715465 it is because you have a collection of href's not a single href. if you want to concatenate them into one string use `textBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, hrefs);`